# GRPC Illegal header value

Tags: c++, grpc, open-telemetry

I am trying to figure out a bug in my application but I am a bit in the dark.
When calling a service, my client crashes when receiving the response with an "illegal header value" assertion error.

I am using open-telemetry and add span-context to my client context like shown in their examples.

```
// inject current context to grpc metadata
  auto current_ctx = opentelemetry::context::RuntimeContext::GetCurrent();
  GrpcClientCarrier carrier(context);
  auto prop = opentelemetry::context::propagation::GlobalTextMapPropagator::GetGlobalPropagator();
  prop->Inject(carrier, current_ctx);
```

The span context is added to all of my services, but only one fails with this error.
I do nothing differently there.
And it looks like the span-id (00-8703a0beea6ff515a32967c40dfb41fb-49b3c2fe1ac932a9-01) is inside the metadata byte array.
If I remove the span context, it works.

```
raise 0x00007ffff67b918b
abort 0x00007ffff6798859
grpc::CoreCodegen::assert_fail(char const*, char const*, int) 0x0000555555769737
grpc::internal::CallOpSet<grpc::internal::CallOpSendInitialMetadata, grpc::internal::CallOpSendMessage, grpc::internal::CallOpRecvInitialMetadata, grpc::internal::CallOpRecvMessage<google::protobuf::MessageLite>, grpc::internal::CallOpClientSendClose, grpc::internal::CallOpClientRecvStatus>::ContinueFillOpsAfterInterception() 0x0000555555dd5c3b
grpc::internal::CallOpSet<grpc::internal::CallOpSendInitialMetadata, grpc::internal::CallOpSendMessage, grpc::internal::CallOpRecvInitialMetadata, grpc::internal::CallOpRecvMessage<google::protobuf::MessageLite>, grpc::internal::CallOpClientSendClose, grpc::internal::CallOpClientRecvStatus>::FillOps(grpc::internal::Call*) 0x0000555555dd5971
grpc::Channel::PerformOpsOnCall(grpc::internal::CallOpSetInterface*, grpc::internal::Call*) 0x00005555557a2482
grpc::internal::Call::PerformOps(grpc::internal::CallOpSetInterface*) 0x00005555557847e7
grpc::internal::BlockingUnaryCallImpl<google::protobuf::MessageLite, google::protobuf::MessageLite>::BlockingUnaryCallImpl(grpc::ChannelInterface*, grpc::internal::RpcMethod const&, grpc::ClientContext*, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&, google::protobuf::MessageLite*) 0x0000555555dd124b
grpc::internal::BlockingUnaryCall<grpc::station::StationId, grpc::station::DefaultResponse, google::protobuf::MessageLite, google::protobuf::MessageLite> client_unary_call.h:45


E1014 11:47:58.117958972 2120287 call.cc:926]                validate_metadata: {"created":"@1634204878.117940102","description":"Illegal header value","file":"/builds/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/validate_metadata.cc","file_line":51,"offset":55,"raw_bytes":"30 30 2d 38 37 30 33 61 30 62 65 65 61 36 66 66 35 31 35 61 33 32 39 36 37 63 34 30 64 66 62 34 31 66 62 2d 34 39 62 33 63 32 66 65 31 61 63 39 33 32 61 39 2d 30 31 7f '00-8703a0beea6ff515a32967c40dfb41fb-49b3c2fe1ac932a9-01.'\u0000"}
E1014 11:47:58.117989343 2120287 call_op_set.h:980]          assertion failed: false
```

Comment: Why does the "raw_bytes" have mixed bytes and string trace context?

Comment: That's the question. I am doing it like in the open-telemetry example.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some value in your context that is not properly encoded for a metadata, such as a newline (or maybe the null Unicode point `\u0000` at the end ?).

I had a similar problem with the access_token_call_credentials plugin and it was my token embedding a tailing newline.